# numpy indexing along a given dimension using a boolean list

Tags: python, numpy

so what i have is an array like this for example:

np.ones(1,1,500,800) and a list of booleans [True,False...True] with len = 500.

What I would like is to index the array along axis 2 and using the boolean list to get something like (1,1,200,800) (assuming there are 200 out of 500 True in the list)

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward:

```py
a = np.ones((1, 1, 500, 300))
b = np.random.random(500) < 0.5
c = a[:, :, b, :]
```